# How to implement Oauth 2.0 in PHPMailer for Exchange Online

Tags: php, azure, authentication, oauth-2.0, phpmailer

As many of you are aware, Microsoft is **deprecating basic authentication** (login and password) for **Exchange online** on 01/10/2022 onwards. You can read the full article over here:

[https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2022/09/01/microsoft-retires-basic-authentication-in-exchange-online/#:~:text=As%20previously%20announced%2C%20we%20are,users%20move%20to%20Modern%20Authentication](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2022/09/01/microsoft-retires-basic-authentication-in-exchange-online/#:%7E:text=As%20previously%20announced%2C%20we%20are,users%20move%20to%20Modern%20Authentication)

I am currently using PHPMailer to send e-mails via SMTP from an application.

**Working example of the current code:**

```
<?php
    include "vendor/autoload.php";
    
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Host = "smtp.office365.com";
    $mail->Port = "587";
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = "my_email@my-company.com";
    $mail->Password = "my_password";
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    $mail->From = "my_email@my-company.com";
    $mail->FromName = "my_name";
    $mail->AddAddress("my_email@my-company.com");
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = "This is a test subject";
    $mail->Body = "Hello, how are you?";
    $mail->Send();
?>
```

I want to transfer from basic authentication to OAuth 2.0. After reading a lot of documentation, searching the web for 3 days, trying and trying, I am not able to get it working.

**Example of my new code:**

```
<?php
    include "vendor/autoload.php";

    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\OAuth;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
    use Stevenmaguire\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Microsoft;
    
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = "smtp.office365.com";
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->AuthType = "XOAUTH2";
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_LOWLEVEL;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    $mail->Port = 587;

    $username = "my_email@my-company.com";
    $clientId = "client_id_from_azure_app_registration";
    $clientSecret = "client_secret_from_azure_app_registration";
    $redirectURI = "my_redirect_uri";
    $Token = "my_token";
    $mail->refresh_token = $Token;

    $provider = new Stevenmaguire\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Microsoft(
        [
            "clientId" => $clientId,
            "clientSecret" => $clientSecret,
            "redirectUri" => $redirectURI
        ]
    );

    $provider->urlAPI = "https://outlook.office365.com/.default";
    $provider->scope = "Mail.Send";

    $mail->setOAuth(
        new OAuth(
            [
                "provider" => $provider,
                "clientId" => $clientId,
                "clientSecret" => $clientSecret,
                "refreshToken" => $Token, 
                "userName" =>$username
            ]
        )
    );

    $mail->From = $username;
    $mail->AddAddress("my_email@my-company.com");   
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = "This is a test subject";
    $mail->Body = "Hello, how are you?";
    $mail->Send();
?>
```

I generate an access token via Postman and use this token in the code above:

[image: Postman screen shot]

The application is configured in Microsoft Azure with the required permissions:

[image: Azure config]

This is the output I get:

```
2022-09-27 13:51:38 Connection: opening to smtp.office365.com:587, timeout=300, options=array()
2022-09-27 13:51:38 Connection: opened
2022-09-27 13:51:38 SMTP INBOUND: "220 AS4P191CA0011.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Tue, 27 Sep 2022 13:51:37 +0000"
2022-09-27 13:51:38 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 AS4P191CA0011.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Tue, 27 Sep 2022 13:51:37 +0000
2022-09-27 13:51:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO
2022-09-27 13:51:38 SMTP INBOUND: "250-AS4P191CA0011.outlook.office365.com Hello [2a02:4780:8:2::25]"
2022-09-27 13:51:38 SMTP INBOUND: "250-SIZE 157286400"
2022-09-27 13:51:38 SMTP INBOUND: "250-PIPELINING"
2022-09-27 13:51:38 SMTP INBOUND: "250-DSN"
2022-09-27 13:51:38 SMTP INBOUND: "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
2022-09-27 13:51:38 SMTP INBOUND: "250-STARTTLS"
2022-09-27 13:51:38 SMTP INBOUND: "250-8BITMIME"
2022-09-27 13:51:38 SMTP INBOUND: "250-BINARYMIME"
2022-09-27 13:51:38 SMTP INBOUND: "250-CHUNKING"
2022-09-27 13:51:38 SMTP INBOUND: "250 SMTPUTF8"
2022-09-27 13:51:38 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-AS4P191CA0011.outlook.office365.com Hello [2a02:4780:8:2::25]250-SIZE 157286400250-PIPELINING250-DSN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-STARTTLS250-8BITMIME250-BINARYMIME250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2022-09-27 13:51:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2022-09-27 13:51:38 SMTP INBOUND: "220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready"
2022-09-27 13:51:38 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
2022-09-27 13:51:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO
2022-09-27 13:51:38 SMTP INBOUND: "250-AS4P191CA0011.outlook.office365.com Hello [2a02:4780:8:2::25]"
2022-09-27 13:51:38 SMTP INBOUND: "250-SIZE 157286400"
2022-09-27 13:51:38 SMTP INBOUND: "250-PIPELINING"
2022-09-27 13:51:38 SMTP INBOUND: "250-DSN"
2022-09-27 13:51:38 SMTP INBOUND: "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
2022-09-27 13:51:38 SMTP INBOUND: "250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2"
2022-09-27 13:51:38 SMTP INBOUND: "250-8BITMIME"
2022-09-27 13:51:38 SMTP INBOUND: "250-BINARYMIME"
2022-09-27 13:51:38 SMTP INBOUND: "250-CHUNKING"
2022-09-27 13:51:38 SMTP INBOUND: "250 SMTPUTF8"
2022-09-27 13:51:38 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-AS4P191CA0011.outlook.office365.com Hello [2a02:4780:8:2::25]250-SIZE 157286400250-PIPELINING250-DSN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2250-8BITMIME250-BINARYMIME250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2022-09-27 13:51:38 Auth method requested: XOAUTH2
2022-09-27 13:51:38 Auth methods available on the server: LOGIN,XOAUTH2

Fatal error: Uncaught League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException: Bad Request in /home/u760208683/vendor/stevenmaguire/oauth2-microsoft/src/Provider/Microsoft.php:79 Stack trace: #0 /home/u760208683/vendor/league/oauth2-client/src/Provider/AbstractProvider.php(628): Stevenmaguire\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Microsoft->checkResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Array) #1 /home/u760208683/vendor/league/oauth2-client/src/Provider/AbstractProvider.php(537): League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider->getParsedResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request)) #2 /home/u760208683/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/OAuth.php(115): League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider->getAccessToken(Object(League\OAuth2\Client\Grant\RefreshToken), Array) #3 /home/u760208683/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/OAuth.php(128): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\OAuth->getToken() #4 /home/u760208683/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php(598): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\OAuth->getOauth64() #5 /home/u760208683/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer in /home/u760208683/vendor/stevenmaguire/oauth2-microsoft/src/Provider/Microsoft.php on line 79
```

**Can anyone point me in the right direction?**

Many thanks in advance!

Kind regards,
Laurents

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but you wrote, that you got an ``access`` token, but in your code snippet you have to insert a ``refresh`` token...

Comment: Hi Biberman, thank you for your reply! Indeed, I realized that as well. But I am not able to gain a refresh token. I only get an access token. I have searched the internet for a solution and if I add 'offline_access' to the scope, I should get a refresh token... But that is not the case unfortunately.

Comment: I got my refresh token by calling the file ``get_oauth_token.php``, which is included in PHPMailer, in a browser. The last line before the last closing bracket is ``echo 'Refresh Token: ', $token->getRefreshToken();``

Comment: When I try to do that, I do get the error:

We're unable to complete your request
unauthorized_client: The client does not exist or is not enabled for consumers. If you are the application developer, configure a new application through the App Registrations in the Azure Portal at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2083908.

Comment: I also got this error message when i used the wrong credentials (Secret ID instead of Secret value, or Secret value and Client ID exchanged/pasted in the wrong input)...

Comment: I double checked that :) It has something to do that I am trying to retrieve a token for business and not for consumer. I think it has something to do with the Stevenmaguire\OAuth2 package that is refering to login.live.com

Comment: I'm also using that package without any changes. Maybe your App registration in azure portal is incorrect...

Comment: I have edited /src/Provider/Microsoft.php
changing the following lines:

protected $urlAuthorize = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize';
protected $urlAccessToken = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token';

and I do get a refresh token now! :)

Comment: I not able to authenticate, I get the following log from PHPMailer:

2022-09-29 11:18:20 SMTP INBOUND: "535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [MRXP264CA0038.FRAP264.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]"
2022-09-29 11:18:20 SERVER -> CLIENT: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [MRXP264CA0038.FRAP264.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]
2022-09-29 11:18:20 SMTP ERROR: AUTH command failed: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [MRXP264CA0038.FRAP264.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2022-09-29 11:18:20 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2022-09-29 11:18:20 SMTP INBOUND: "221 2.0.0 Service closing transmission channel

Comment: I get the same error message, when i try to login with an email address, that is not the main user from our tenant. Unfortunately i don't know how to fix it, because [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73879796/how-to-configure-an-app-in-azure-portal-for-multiple-email-addresses-that-are-i) has still no answer...

Comment: Thanks anyway for all your help! I hope we can both find the answer quickly :)

Comment: I was able to find a solution in the end, read this topic:

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/2116#issuecomment-1263508519

Comment: I'm glady that you found a solution. But i think it doesn't help me because in my case the PHPMailer is used without user interaction, but instead through a script, that is called by the Windows task scheduler. And because i found today this: ``
Note As per the current test with SMTP Oauth 2.0 client credential flow with non-interactive sign in is not supported.``, i think there is actually no solution for my use case. Besides that: If your question is solved, please convert your comment to an answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
Fatal error: Uncaught League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException:
```

This error is due to the fact you are providing an access_token to send the mail instead of a refresh_token.

First of all, add the scope offline_access to get a refresh_token in your authorise url and save it somewhere in your app ( expiration is 24 hour or 90 days depends on type of app)
once you have the refresh token you can send as many mails as you want with the same token.

you can get new one by providing another non expired refresh token in the url and change grant_type to refresh_token and add the key refresh_token.